# Meta tag "title" for all pages on the website

Tags: wordpress, meta

is there something that I can do, to use `<meta name="title"/>` for all pages on my website at once.

Answer (score 0):

First include this in header file than write like this :

```
<meta name="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?><?php wp_title(); ?>">
```

Hope this helps.

Thanks,
Rakhi

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use SEO plugin for this purpose. There many free plugins providing SEO functionalities for wordpress. "Yoast" or "All in One SEO" are one of the popular plugins.

When installed and activated such plugin, on your "page" or "post" (or any custom post type) you get an option to add custom title for your current page / post you are editing. This way you can set unique title for each page / post .